# Sumar tiempos e imprimir la suma

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy haciendo un pequeño script con python y selenium que muestra que comprueba cada 5 segundos si un usuario de whatsapp esta en línea y si lo está imprime una línea así "en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:30" , me gustaría recibir solo un mensaje con el tiempo en total que estuvo en línea.

ejemplo:
Ahora recibo esto:

```
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:01
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:08
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:15
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:22
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:30
```

Y me gustaría recibir esto: (o similar)

```
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:01 inicio
en línea 11/21/2021, 14:35:30 fin
total 29 segundos
```

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\python\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')


time.sleep(25)

usuarios=[]

def inicio():
    now = datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

    try: 

        h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/span')

        usuarios.append(h1.text)
        last = usuarios.pop()

        if last == ("en línea"):
            print (last,date_time) 

        
        time.sleep(5)

    except:

        pass

while True:
    inicio()
```

Comment: nadie me puede dar una solución?, no se muy bien por donde empezar

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esto te funcione:

```
def inicio():
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")


try: 

    h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/span')

    usuarios.append(h1.text)
    last = usuarios.pop()

    if last == ("en línea"):
        date_start= date_time.now()
        print (last,date_time) 

    else:
        if date_start is not None:
            date_finish = date_time.now()
            print(f'utlima vez visto {date_finish} tiempo en linea {date_finish - date_start}')
        else:
            pass
    
    time.sleep(5)

except:

    pass
```